# How to animate svg paths with different speeds, by fixing a rotation center point?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

**1. Introduction**

I have an image that i want to animate its specific 'paths' around a center point.

For example 'path1' will rotate at t=1s, and 'path2' at t=3s.

**2. The question:**

How can this be done?

**3.Clarification**

The image is on a simple index page.

**4.This is the source image file**

```
           <g id="first">
            <path id="path1" fill="#ed1c24" opacity="1.00" d=" M 7.01 7.01 C 104.67 6.99 202.33 6.99 299.99 7.01 C 300.01 104.67 300.01 202.33 299.99 299.99 C 202.33 300.00 104.67 300.01 7.01 299.99 C 7.00 202.33 6.99 104.67 7.01 7.01 M 33.01 32.01 C 32.99 113.67 32.99 195.33 33.01 276.99 C 114.00 277.01 195.00 277.01 275.99 276.99 C 276.01 195.33 276.00 113.67 275.99 32.01 C 195.00 31.99 114.00 31.99 33.01 32.01 Z" />
            </g>
            <g id="second">
            <path id="path2" fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 153.11 60.95 C 153.80 60.95 155.19 60.95 155.89 60.95 C 164.16 84.01 170.90 107.63 178.27 131.00 C 193.87 131.15 209.34 132.65 225.03 131.99 C 231.77 133.78 238.79 132.61 245.68 133.11 C 247.47 134.01 247.60 136.84 245.75 137.75 C 228.10 151.08 210.95 165.34 193.10 178.24 C 200.20 200.70 205.97 223.63 212.89 246.17 C 213.90 248.26 211.70 251.09 209.51 249.75 C 191.40 237.05 173.47 224.11 155.49 211.23 C 154.51 210.75 153.61 210.91 152.79 211.69 C 135.34 224.34 117.79 236.83 100.20 249.29 C 98.13 251.48 94.85 248.71 96.11 246.17 C 103.03 223.63 108.79 200.70 115.90 178.24 C 98.05 165.34 80.90 151.08 63.25 137.75 C 61.40 136.84 61.52 134.01 63.32 133.12 C 70.21 132.61 77.23 133.78 83.97 131.99 C 99.66 132.65 115.13 131.15 130.73 131.00 C 138.19 107.66 144.91 84.03 153.11 60.95 Z" />
            </g>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way to rotate specific paths of an svg file with your desired speed.

*Here is the code that worked for me:*

```html
<svg width="100pt" height="100pt" viewBox="0 0 160 160" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="first">
    <path id="path1" fill="#ed1c24" opacity="1.00" d=" M 7.01 7.01 C 104.67 6.99 202.33 6.99 299.99 7.01 C 300.01 104.67 300.01 202.33 299.99 299.99 C 202.33 300.00 104.67 300.01 7.01 299.99 C 7.00 202.33 6.99 104.67 7.01 7.01 M 33.01 32.01 C 32.99 113.67 32.99 195.33 33.01 276.99 C 114.00 277.01 195.00 277.01 275.99 276.99 C 276.01 195.33 276.00 113.67 275.99 32.01 C 195.00 31.99 114.00 31.99 33.01 32.01 Z" />
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 80 80" to="360 80 80" begin="0s" dur="1.00s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </g>
  <g id="second">
    <path id="path2" fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 153.11 60.95 C 153.80 60.95 155.19 60.95 155.89 60.95 C 164.16 84.01 170.90 107.63 178.27 131.00 C 193.87 131.15 209.34 132.65 225.03 131.99 C 231.77 133.78 238.79 132.61 245.68 133.11 C 247.47 134.01 247.60 136.84 245.75 137.75 C 228.10 151.08 210.95 165.34 193.10 178.24 C 200.20 200.70 205.97 223.63 212.89 246.17 C 213.90 248.26 211.70 251.09 209.51 249.75 C 191.40 237.05 173.47 224.11 155.49 211.23 C 154.51 210.75 153.61 210.91 152.79 211.69 C 135.34 224.34 117.79 236.83 100.20 249.29 C 98.13 251.48 94.85 248.71 96.11 246.17 C 103.03 223.63 108.79 200.70 115.90 178.24 C 98.05 165.34 80.90 151.08 63.25 137.75 C 61.40 136.84 61.52 134.01 63.32 133.12 C 70.21 132.61 77.23 133.78 83.97 131.99 C 99.66 132.65 115.13 131.15 130.73 131.00 C 138.19 107.66 144.91 84.03 153.11 60.95 Z" />
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 80 80" to="360 80 80" begin="0s" dur="3.00s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </g>
</svg>
```